# Confused about Tokens

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, spl-token-program, mint

I am very new to Solana and am going through the Bootcamp on SOLANA YT channel. Can someone explain me what are tokens? Why do we need tokens? What is Mint? How is SPL different from SOL?

Answer (score 1):

Tokens(SPL Tokens) are digital assets that are built on top of a Solana blockchain platform. They can be used to represent a wide variety of things, such as currencies, assets, or even voting rights.

**Why do we need tokens?**

Tokens are useful for a number of reasons. First, they can be used to create new and innovative financial products and services. For example, decentralized exchanges allow users to trade tokens without the need for a trusted intermediary. Second, tokens can be used to represent ownership of assets. For example, security tokens can be used to represent ownership of shares in a company. Third, tokens can be used to create new governance models. For example, some projects use tokens to give their community members a say in how the project is run.

**What is Mint?**

Minting in Solana is the process of creating new digital assets on the Solana blockchain. This can include tokens, NFTs, and other types of digital collectibles.

To mint a new asset on Solana, you will need to interact with a smart contract. Smart contracts are self-executing contracts that reside on the blockchain and can be used to create and manage digital assets.

The specific steps involved in minting a new asset will vary depending on the type of asset you are minting and the smart contract you are using. However, in general, the process will involve the following steps:

Connect to the Solana network using a wallet such as Phantom or Solflare.
Interact with the smart contract to mint the new asset.
Pay the required transaction fees.
Once the transaction is complete, the new asset will be created and added to your wallet.

Minting assets on Solana is a relatively straightforward process, and there are a number of different minting tools and platforms available to make it even easier.

**How is SPL different from SOL?**

SPL stands for Solana Program Library. It is a set of standards and tools that make it easy to create and manage tokens on the Solana blockchain. SOL is the native currency of the Solana blockchain. It is used to pay for transaction fees and to power applications on the network.

SPL tokens are different from SOL in a few ways. First, SPL tokens can be created and managed by anyone, while SOL is created and managed by the Solana Foundation. Second, SPL tokens can be used to represent a wide variety of things, while SOL is primarily used as a currency. Third, SPL tokens can be used to create new applications and services, while SOL is used to power the Solana network.